# Append table row with check-box

Tags: jquery

my function:

```
$("#btn2").click(function(){
    var n = $( '#t01 tr' ).length;
    $("table").append("<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="Check" value= "1"></input></td><td>"+ n +"</td><td>"+ $("#team_name").val() +"</td></tr>");
});
```

The problem is the `<input>`-Tag. I have also tried:

```
"<tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"Check\" value= \"1\"></input></td><td>"+ n +"</td><td>"+ $("#team_name").val() +"</td></tr>"
```

can anyone help me please

Comment: `$("#btn2").click(function () {
    var n = $('#t01 tr').length;
    $("table").append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox " name="Check " value= "1 "></input></td><td>" + n + "</td><td>' + $("#team_name").val() + '</td></tr>');
});` - since you are using `"` for attribute quotes use `'` for string literal

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're missing a quote character somewhere.
Since Javascript and html both allow you to define strings with single quotes too, you can use both.
Try this :

```
$("#btn2").click(function(){
    var n = $( '#t01 tr' ).length;
    $("table").append("<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='Check' value= '1'></input></td><td>"+ n +"</td><td>"+ $("#team_name").val() +"</td></tr>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
my function:

$('#btn2').click(function(){
    var n = $( '#t01 tr' ).length;
    $('table').append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="Check" value= "1"></input></td><td>'+ n +'</td><td>'+ $("#team_name").val() +'</td></tr>');
});
```